# Missing required arguments: input_tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I've trained a model using EfficientNet and after no errors in training, I substituted the model into [Tensorflow Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)'s included object_detection Python notebook.

```py
def run_inference_for_single_image(model, image):
  image = np.asarray(image)
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis,...]

  model_fn = model.signatures['serving_default']


  output_dict = model_fn(input_tensor)

  num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
  output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
  output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections

  output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

  return output_dict

def show_inference(model, image_path):
  image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))

  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)

# image_path here is just a path to a .jpg
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  show_inference(detection_model, image_path)
```

The following error was raised:

```
TypeError: signature_wrapper(*, input_tensor) missing required arguments: input_tensor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Incompatible shapes: [1,256,256] vs. [1,1,3]
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/Preprocessor/sub}}]]
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Reshape_11/_112]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Incompatible shapes: [1,256,256] vs. [1,1,3]
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/Preprocessor/sub}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_signature_wrapper_73496]
```

The model was trained and tested on (black & white) pngs which is the key difference between the example (besides it being a different model that the example has). Converting the pngs to jpgs changes the root errors:

```
Invalid argument:  input must be 4-dimensional[1,256,256]
```

Short of starting again with jpgs and training/testing that, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: `tensorflow2.x` object detection api has trained models & how to to train your own model. But by default, the training/evaluation is on `JPEG` format. So if you have any other codec format for your images, you will have to convert them. Let me know if you need help with that and try it out

Comment: I should have updated the post. This was what I tried next with success.

Comment: I'll wrap this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.X Object Detection API has pre-trained models & the github repository has good documentation on how to to train your own model.

But by default, the training/evaluation is on `JPEG` format. So if you have any other codec format for your images, you will have to convert them.

The following snipped will easily convert your existing images to jpeg codec and save with the same file name + `.jpg`

To run

`python convert.py folder_with_images`

```
#convert.py
from PIL import Image     
import os
import sys 

path = sys.argv[1] # Source Folder
if path[-1] != '/':
    path = path +'/' 
for file in os.listdir(path):      
        extension = file.split('.')[-1]
        name = file.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
        fileLoc = path+file
        img = Image.open(fileLoc)
        new = Image.new("RGB", img.size, (255, 255, 255))
        new.paste(img,None) # save the new image with jpg as extension
        new.save(path+name, 'JPEG', quality=100)
        if(extension != 'jpg'): #remove the old image
            os.remove(path+file)
```